# How do I make a list for a drop down menu in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

The title may be a bit obscure. I am trying to produce a drop-down menu in django based on the following code:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   person_list = PersonYear.objects.all().values('person__pk', 'person__TLA')
   person = forms.CharField(label='Säljare',widget = 
            forms.Select(choices=person_list))
```

I was trying this, because my understanding is that I need a list of the form

```
person_list = [(1 , 'Abc'), (2, 'CDe'),...]
```

but my person_list has the form

```
<QuerySet [{'person_pk : '1', 'person_TLA : 'Abc'}, {'person_pk : '2', 
'person_TLA : 'CDe'}].......>
```

So it does not work. How should I be doing this. I want to get a drop-down menu with the TLA:s from which I then can identify the pk.

Comment: Use `values_list` instead. That'll return a tuple with the values you want

Answer (score 1):

You should use `forms.ModelChoiceField` for this. It takes a queryset and you don't need to customise the widget.

```
person = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Säljare', queryset=PersonYear.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. But it calls for a further question: if I want to augment the queryset with one that is None (so that there is a None in the dropdown menu), how do I ado that?

Comment: It will do that automatically if you set `required=False` on the field.